# Average Time & Display In Specifc Format (Coldfusion)

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, date-format, datediff

**Edit:** Thanks to barnyr I have the average in seconds, so now I just need to convert it to the correct format. Unfortunately the Coldfusion functions noted by Peter only take a datetime object, so I'm back to being stumped by the conversion.

I have a two-fold question. I need to generate the average time it took Y users to complete a task, and then display the result in a specific format: x Years x Months x Weeks x Days x Hours x Minutes x Seconds.

My backend database is SQL Server 2008, and I'm running the queries through Coldfusion 10. Both columns are datetime fields.

The query is (similar to):

```
SELECT    Started_Date, Completed_Date
FROM      tbl_progress
WHERE     0=0
```

I then need to iterate through the query results, get the difference between the Completed_Date and Started_Date (ie. duration), average the results, and display as noted above.

From another thread on Stackoverflow I got the following code, but it will only work for the days/hours/minutes/seconds sections of the required format.

```
<cfloop query="complete_time">
    <cfset completed = ParseDateTime(complete_time.Completed_Date) />
    <cfset started = ParseDateTime(complete_time.Started_Date) />
    <cfset difference = (completed - started) /> 
    <cfset fixed_diff = Fix(difference) />  
    <cfset days = fixed_diff /> 
    <cfset hours = TimeFormat(difference, "H") /> 
    <cfset minutes = TimeFormat(difference, "m") />  
    <cfset seconds = TimeFormat(difference, "s")/ >
</cfloop>
```

I need to know how/where to do the averaging, and how to get the years/months/weeks values for my required format. Date math is definitely not my best subject! Thanks.

Comment: Instead of TimeFormat, do [`Hour(difference)`](http://cfdocs.org/hour) and [`Year(difference)`](http://cfdocs.org/year) etc  (Or perhaps needs to be `Year(completed)-Year(started)` or whatever)

Comment: Very interesting. Looks like Year(completed) - Year(started) is what gives the correct results (or at least results that match my original calculations. Thanks Peter.

Comment: Have you looked at CFLIB.org? That's usually my first stop when ColdFusion lacks a function I need. Like [convertSecondsToTimeString()](http://cflib.org/udf/convertSecondsToTimeString), which takes a number of seconds as an input parameter and returns the time broken down like so: 4d 12h 30s. It shouldn't be too difficult to expand it to use Years, Months, etc. There's also [secsToTime()](http://cflib.org/udf/secsToTime) which is similar.

Comment: A question though: years and months don't always have to the same number of days. How are you going to resolve that?

Comment: Thanks Al, I'll take a look around CFLib. As far as the number of days in a year/month ideally the solution would handle that automatically. I'm assuming the Coldfusion functions Peter mentioned would have accounted for that somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the work in the database if you possibly can:

```
SELECT    Started_Date, 
          Completed_Date, 
          DATEDIFF(Second, Started_Date, Completed_Date) AS sec_diff
FROM      tbl_progress
```

You can then compute the seconds into minutes, hours etc in ColdFusion.

As you work through the results, you could sum up the `sec_diff` values. Then divide them by the number of row in your result set.

You could also average the results in a query. Tave a look at SQL's `AVG()` function.

I'm not near a SQL server, but you may be able to use the following:

```
SELECT    Started_Date, 
          Completed_Date, 
          DATEDIFF(Second, Started_Date, Completed_Date) AS sec_diff,
          AVG(DATEDIFF(Second, Started_Date, Completed_Date)) AS average_task_time
FROM      tbl_progress
```

Comment: Yeah, I would also like to do the work in the SQL, but now I'm wondering how to combine your response w/ the functionality from Peter's comment to my question. That way there's no complicated math to work through and probably get wrong :)

Comment: I edited your answer to provide the working SQL query that returns an average in seconds. I'd like to somehow convert that back to a date, so I can use the Coldfusion functions from Peter, but I'm not quite sure how that would work. Thanks for the help barnyr.

Comment: have you tried 'select Completed_date - Started_Date from tbl_progress'? I think that ought to give you a datetime as an offset from Jan 1 1900, which you may be able to work with

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `datediff` function in sql server to get the number of seconds.  Then in ColdFusion you don't use timeformat, you do math.  `Timeformat()` takes a datetime object and returns a string.

Comment: I like the idea of doing datediff, but the Coldfusion year/hour/day functionality is very attractive in its simplicity.